# Fortify SCA exclude test folder\files

Tags: fortify

How can I exclude test directories in a Java Project from being scanned by  Fortify sca. The directories are structured in the following way -

```
/src/main/xyz/pqr
/src/main/xyz/test/abc
/src/test/xyz
```

I want to exclude any files under folders named test from being scanned. I am not sure how to use the -exclude command line parameter to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following:

```
-exclude "**/test/*"
```

Answer (score 1):

use -exclude /src/main/xyz/test/**    if you are using command prompt to run then backslash

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by https://stackoverflow.com/a/36754012/6641032, the exclusion pattern expects the path starting from drive letter. The wildcard ** notation can match as many folder levels as there is, but the path has to start from drive root, so can't be **/folder/**. I'm on Source Analyser 16.10 and it worked for me.