# Fortify SCA Exclude Multiple Files

Tags: fortify

With the sourceanalyzer, how can I provide multiple file/path exclusions during translation?

Following the example from: [Fortify SCA exclude test folder\files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181736/fortify-sca-exclude-test-folder-files)

`/src/main/xyz/pqr/Abc.java
/src/main/xyz/test/abc.xsd
/src/test/xyz/Xyz.java`

I have tried adding multiple -exclude flags, as well as different delimiters, with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the Scan Wizard and review the resultant `.bat` file, you can see how they are invoking `sourceanalyzer`.  For your particular question, you can create an argument file like so:

```
-exclude "/src/main/xyz/pqr/Abc.java"
-exclude "/src/main/xyz/test/abc.xsd"
-exclude "/src/test/xyz/Xyz.java"
```

Name it something like Exclude.args and then invoke `sourceanalyzer` like so:

```
sourceanalyzer.exe -b MyBuild @Exclude.args
```

Comment: This does work..I had tried this before, but something must have been missing. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: How can resolve the same issue in  Linux ?

Answer (score 3):

I was working from an Azure DevOps Pipeline using fortify Translate batchscript task. In this environment it worked to add multiple -exclude flags:

```
 steps:
- task: BatchScript@1
  displayName: 'Fortify Translate JavaScript'
  inputs:
    filename: '$(FORTIFYSCA)\sourceanalyzer.exe'
    arguments: '-debug -verbose -b $(Build.ApplicationName) $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\**\*.js -exclude node_modules\**\* -exclude coverage\**\*'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the VS 2015 addin for Fortify scan. I sorted out the files I want to skip. I created a new filter and saved the results in a separate folder apart from Critical, High, etc.
This way the selected files were avoided from the final result.